# Doxygen and C# ValueTuple

Tags: c#, doxygen, valuetuple

I am using Doxygen 1.8.17 to document a C# project and I am trying to document this:

```
/// <summary>
/// returns the LU factorization of a general m-by-n matrix A as: P*A = L*U. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="matrixA">a matrix m-by-n</param>
public static (double[,] L, double[,] U, double[,] P) LUDecomposition(double[,] matrixA)
{
  ...
  return (L, U, P);
}
```

Return type of the method is a [ValueTuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.8).
Doxygen process it as a *static Public Attributes* of the class, not as a *Member Function* and only shows L as return value:

[image]

Is there an option to make Doxygen able to deal with ValueTuple ?
Does anyone has a workaround ?
I would like avoid to define a special class for this output.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Guix

Comment: I think this is not (yet) supported by doxygen, see also C#: Methods returning a tuple are documented with a crippled signature (https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/7633).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did not see this GitHub issue !